# What is the advantage of non-embeded tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I discovered embeded tomcat, and I find it very convenient!

While it seems that we used non-embeded Tomcat more *frequently* in the past, (there were more available tutorials and books about non-embeded Tomcat), the use of non-embedded Tomcat continues.

What is the advantage of non-embedded Tomcat? Why doesn't everyone use embedded Tomcat all the time?

Also:

> 1. Where is embedded Tomcat document and site?
>      I looked forward embed tomcat document and site, but could not find it.
> 2. Is there any difference between embedded Tomcat and non-embedded Tomcat in source code?

Comment: One can run multiple web applications on a separate Tomcat server. This is not possible with an embedded Tomcat. With the move to microservices, this has become less popular.

Comment: @BoristheSpider user could start multiple app with embed tomcat, it's very convenient~!

Comment: Yes, on **different ports** in **different JVMs** with **no shared state**. I could of course add Hazelcast to share state and Nginx to run (effectively) on the same port, but that is a massive step up in complexity over just sharing a Tomcat instance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider An embedded Tomcat instance can run any number of web applications. Any number of ports (including just one), on the same JVM, with as much shared-state as you want. It's just extremely *common* to run a single application with an embedded Tomcat instance.

Comment: @Christopher yes, of course you are right. I should have been clearer, that in the common use case (such as Spring Boot) a single application is deployed to its own embedded server instance.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody has different requirements and use-cases. For your use-case, embedded usage apparently seems ideal. This is not true for every situation.

Running embedded Tomcat is like turning the "servlet container" inside-out and, instead of the container (Tomcat) hosting the application, instead the application hosts the container. It's *inversion of control*, if you like that kind of metaphor.

Using embedded Tomcat requires that the application write against Tomcat-specific APIs. That may or may not increase complexity for you or your application.

Service-based programs such as Tomcat typically have systems monitoring them to ensure they stay running and auto-restart if they do not continue to run. There are fewer opportunities to use existing tools for that purpose if you switch to an embedded strategy: your application instead must monitor the embedded container's health and take action whenever necessary.

Resource-management can be problematic when using an embedded container. If you have a dozen web applications that should all work together, does it make more sense to have a single container instance hosting those individual applications, or should you bundle them together into a single program with an embedded container instance inside? What if you want to upgrade only a single application? You'd need to rebuild the entire package just to update one component. Or should you deploy them each as a separate application with its own embedded container? That usually means multiple JVMs which means higher memory requirements, port-conflicts, and other similar resource-related issues.

There are lots of valid use-cases for both embedded and non-embedded Tomcat. Fortunately, you have a choice.

> Where is embedded Tomcat document and site? I looked forward embed tomcat document and site, but could not find it.

It's primarily in the [Tomcat javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html).

> Is there any difference between embedded Tomcat and non-embedded Tomcat in source code?

It's the same product.

Comment: Worth noting on the monitoring part, that Spring Boot has support for [running as a UNIX daemon](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service) which addresses many of those concerns. Obviously there are other shortcomings, but it's a start.